# Under-clocking an 10gb Ethernet SFP+ module

Tags: fpga, ethernet

The Xilinx device on the Picozed board is a version of the Zynq 7030. The 7030 in general has a GTX transceiver, which in principle is rated to 12.5Gb/s SERDES with the relevant line coding for 10gig Ethernet.

Unfortunately, the specific chip on the Picozed has its GTX transceiver down rated to a reduced 6.6Gb/s.

Is it possible to use a reduced line rate with off the shelf 10gig Ethernet networking hardware (modules and switches)?

Without knowing enough about the precise tech, at first glance, I can't see a problem in principle with the TX side since it would result in a reduced implicit clock frequency. On the RX side it seems more problematic: the other end would need to either realise or be told to transmit at a reduced rate.

Is this something that can be made to work?

Comment: what kind of SFP+ module are you using? (also, how much data rate do you *need* to achieve?)

Comment: There are SFP(+?) transceivers available designed for 8 Gbps Fibre Channel applications. Those might be slightly better tuned for your application than a 10 GbE part.

Comment: @marcusmüller the module is a design decision, but likely an MMF module. The speed we would like to achieve is as high as possible. The max the source could ever reach would be around 13Gb/s and we'd like to be at close as possible to that. The effect of reduced rate is to reduce our effective duty cycle.

Comment: @thephoton how does that work? Presumably we'd then need to replace the whole data path with that relevant standard?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to run strictly to the standard. I'm just saying if you're operating at 6.6 Gbps, then a part designed for 8.5 Gbps is closer to that than one designed for 10.3125 Gbps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the simpler SFP+ transceivers (direct attach copper cable, short-reach optical fiber) are really little more than analog devices and wouldn't care about the clock (fun fact: friends of mine use SFP optical transmitters to simply distribute a 10 MHz clock, and it works).

None of the stock networking hardware would be prepaed for a 50% rate mismatch, and I'd doubt their PLLs would lock reliably.

So, while point-to-point between devices using relatively dumb SFP+ transceivers might work with arbitrary clocks, I'd not expect functionality with stock networking hardware. It's more likely that you can convince your Zynq's transmitter to work at the full rate than that...

I don't know whether that's viable on your board, but maybe you could use the PCIe endpoints to have 2 or 4 lanes to a 10 GigE network card.

Comment: I feared as much. So the issue is one of having the end point support a reduced clock rate. Perhaps a chat to the vendor would be in order...

Comment: Don't think the vendor will do much – it's a package speed grade restriction of the FPGA. As said, maybe you can convince the SERDES, which is very likely the same silicon, to work at higher rates although Xilinx doesn't want to qualify these packages for that, either for technical or market segmentation reasons.

Comment: Having read rather more about this, there is the option to auto-negotiate a lower speed using a copper channel. It seems many setups would support an auto-negotiation to to the 5GBASE-T standard. Curiously, this only seems to ever happen through a negotiation step. I _think_ the modules are capable of the negotiation step, but I'm still working through how one actually informs them of the requirement to back off - I assume through the low speed serial link.

Comment: AN is done in-band with some sort of machester-encoded data, IIRC.  For nBASE-T, I think you would need to use SFP to copper adapters that support nBASE-T.  But even then, I don't think it would help you much, as I think the link will be USXGMII, which always runs at 10G and simply duplicates symbols to run at the lower rates.

Answer (score 1):

While the SFP+ modules themselves might work at a lower rate (and if they don't contain CDRs, then there should be no issues with running at pretty much whatever rate you like), whatever is at the other end generally expects the data rate to be within something like +/- 200 ppm or so.  If it's outside of this range, the link will not come up.  Also, bear in mind that the recovered RX clock is hardly ever re-used for TX, so your receiver would still have to work at 10G.  Most CDR circuits these days don't even use PLLs in the loop, they generate a half rate clock and then use phase interpolators, this way one PLL can be shared across several TX and RX channels.  And then in many cases the RX data is synchronized back into the TX clock domain with an elastic buffer, so even if the RX channel did lock onto the data, the elastic buffer would either overflow or underflow continuously and the link would be unusable.